# Insert data with Zend_Form and Zend_Db_Table with relationship type 'many-to-many'

Tags: zend-framework, many-to-many, zend-form, zend-db-table

I have a form generated by `Zend_Form`. How do I include the data in the database by `Zend_Db_Table` in table with relationship type many-to-many?

Please see the code: http://pastebin.com/u3C6TQKi and image example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should insert parent table. You can get insert row id. So insert child data with parent row id. It is best way. Also you can write single query and run it single time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is a good alternative.  But the ideal would be to just give a simple insert($data), that Zend could insert the data in the parent table and then save in both tables, according to $_referenceMap. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: sorry. I have not experience with $_referenceMap